# Is better use useState or useRef with a multiple input form?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm working on a fairly large form. I have my own component where I fetch data and then pass data to the form component.
The doubt is this:

- Is it better to use a ref containing the data object?
- Or can I use `useState` ?

These data within the form can be modified by the user whenever he wants.

es:

```
const data={
name:"",
bio:"",
location:""
.....
.....
}
```

Is better use:

```
const ref = useRef(data) or const[user,setUser]=useState(data)
```

Shouldn't I avoid more renders and use the ref ? Does it cause any cause when I enter edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between useState and useRef is that:

If you update the state, your component will re-render
If you update the value stored in your ref, nothing will happen in dom.
If you don’t need the component to re-render useRef may be a good option.

in your case when you change any key from data object using ref that time nothing will changed in your dom.
if you only storing the value that time useRef is better option.